# How to put heading and nav on the same line (not working)

Tags: html, css

Basically what's happening is that my h1 and my nav elements aren't going on the same line. I tried adding a width of 100% and float left and right properties on h1 and nav but still it's not on the same line. I put some gibberish in the h1 to show you that the leveling is off by very little. Help!

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>
            Personality Speakes Before You
            </title>
            <meta charset='utf-8'> 
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1>Anum kdljflkasjfdlajsdlfjslfjsalkdfjld;skjgl;j</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
 body  {
    background-color: azure;
    font-family: cursive;
}
    header {
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    float:left;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
ul {
        color: darkslategray;
    }

li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try change your floats to `display: inline-block`, and set the header to `white-space: nowrap`:

```css
body  {
  background-color: azure;
  font-family: cursive;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  color: darkslategray;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Anum</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

> **Note:** Since the font sizes are so big, see the full effect in "Full page"
>   mode

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but what if I had a smaller h1, like only "Anum", yet I still wanted to float my links/nav on the right side? How would that work?

Comment: Didn't work :( Not sure what else to do....wonder how other web devs are able to do this

Comment: The above code works fine in the snippet; h1 on the left side and nav on the right. Are you using some other code on your site?

Answer (score 0):

The h1 and nav are too wide to fit on one line, so it kinda depends on what you want to happen then as to how to address it. An easy fix is to use a media query to resize the font of those elements when they start to overlap.

```css
body  {
    background-color: azure;
    font-family: cursive;
}
    header {
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    float:left;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
ul {
        color: darkslategray;
    }

li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  h1,li {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  h1,li {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  h1,li {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Personality Speakes Before You
  </title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Anum kdljflkasjfdlajsdlfjslfjsalkdfjld;skjgl;j</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you can use responsive font size units like `vw` that scale based on the page width.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

body  {
    background-color: azure;
    font-family: cursive;
}
    header {
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    float:left;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
ul {
        color: darkslategray;
    }

li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Personality Speakes Before You
  </title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Anum kdljflkasjfdlajsdlfjslfjsalkdfjld;skjgl;j</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you can use other techniques like hiding the vavigation in a hidden menu when you size the browser down and they no longer fit on one line. Then you use a link/button to show the hidden menu.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with your concepts of vm and queries, and also my h1 was supposed to be only "Anum" but I put extra to show the unleveling. What if my h1 was only "Anum"? How would I keep the h1 and nav on the same line then?